# Golang compare numbers

Tags: go, types, assertion

I have two `interface{}`s `a` and `b` from JSON decoding and user input, let's say:

```
var a interface{} = ...
var b interface{} = ...
```

I know they are numbers. They could be any of the following types:

```
unit
unit8
uint16
uint32
uint64
int
int8
int16
int32
int64
float
float32
float64
```

I wrote some test code as follows. It turned out that when a variable is `int`, it will fail with `int64` assertion.

```
var a interface{} = 1
v, f := a.(int64)
fmt.Println(v, f) //0 false
v1, f1 := a.(int)
fmt.Println(v1, f1) //1 true
```

So now my question is as follows: in order to compare these two numbers, do I have to test all the permutations of these more than 10 types just in order to get the types of these two `interface{}` variables? Ideally, I just want to cast them to `int64` or `float64`, but if they are `int` or `float`, I have no way to find them until exhausted all possible types.

Comment: In the more general case (i.e. outside of JSON) you could just create a type switch - https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#type_switch - and only create cases for the types you 'care' about. Have the `default` case return an error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your input comes from JSON input, then it's a `float64`, as per the [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal):

> To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:
>
> - bool, for JSON booleans
> - float64, for JSON numbers
> - string, for JSON strings
> - []interface{}, for JSON arrays
> - map[string]interface{}, for JSON objects
> - nil for JSON null

If its comes from user input, it is whatever you decided it was when you read it, so you shouldn't have any problem to get the right type.

Comment: Aha! Thanks. That makes sense. I think key is to stick to `int64` in my user input parser logic.

Comment: These two interfaces are still possible from JSON or user input, so that  they could either be float64 or int64. Seems a 2x2 metrics comparison is still inevitable.

Comment: @ElgsQianChen If you are unmarshalling JSON into a `map[string]interface{}`, the `encoding/json` package _guarantees_ that all numbers will be `float64`. If you're unmarshalling into a struct, you can just make the field whatever numeric type you need, or use [`json.Number`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Number).